# How is HIDL implemented for Bluetooth module?

Tags: android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, hal, hidl

I was browsing for `AOSP` bluetooth code to know more about `HIDL`.

As per my understanding, `HIDL` provides an interface between `System services` and `HAL layer`.

But as per official android doc [here](https://source.android.com/devices/bluetooth)  , It seems that `HIDL` is interface between `bluetooth stack(/system/bt)` and bluetooth firmware implementation.

[image]

Shouldn't `HIDL` be present between Bluetooth process services and bluetooth stack? 
Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you have to ask is which parts of the whole Bluetooth stack can be provided by Android and which parts have to be provided by the hardware/device manufacturer.

Google probably decided that all they need from a hardware/device manufacturer is what is described in the Bluetooth HIDL interfaces and that they provide the rest of the stack in the Android framework.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your understanding is based on 2 and 3 in the diagram, but the diagram you posted here is based on 4, which you don't need the HAL layer. Vendor can just implement the HIDL interface.

[image]

Comment: As per Android doc : The default Bluetooth stack is provided in AOSP and is located in system/bt. The stack implements the generic Bluetooth HAL.                                                           That means Bluetooth stack is implementation of HAL.

Comment: My question is if Bluetooth stack is HAL implementation then why HIDL is present between stack and controller implementation?